# How to get path to USB drive on Linux in Qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have successfully compiled libusb with Qt and can now receive events when usb device is connected and when disconnected.

Now I need to get path to the directory. This seems fairly easy under Windows, as I can use `QDir::drives()` according to [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#drives).

So for Windows this returns C:\ , F:\ etc. and I can the write to these locations easily.

However on Linux, all I have is [USB PID and VID](http://www.voti.nl/docs/usb-pid.html) and I have no idea how to get a working path to the root of the USB. I need to write some files there using `QFile`

Is there a universal cross-platform solution?

Comment: Note that on Linux, USB drives may not be mounted automatically!

Comment: solution in my answer can take care of this - just call `QStorageInfo::isValid()` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstorageinfo.html#isValid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this code to do exactly what I need:

```
foreach (const QStorageInfo &storage, QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes()) {

   qDebug() << storage.rootPath();
   if (storage.isReadOnly())
       qDebug() << "isReadOnly:" << storage.isReadOnly();

   qDebug() << "name:" << storage.name();
   qDebug() << "fileSystemType:" << storage.fileSystemType();
   qDebug() << "size:" << storage.bytesTotal()/1000/1000 << "MB";
   qDebug() << "availableSize:" << storage.bytesAvailable()/1000/1000 << "MB";
}
```

Output:

```
"/run"
name: ""
fileSystemType: "tmpfs"
size: 6748 MB
availableSize: 6729 MB
"/"
name: ""
fileSystemType: "ext4"
size: 64370 MB
availableSize: 22236 MB
"/run/lock"
name: ""
fileSystemType: "tmpfs"
size: 5 MB
availableSize: 5 MB
"/home"
name: ""
fileSystemType: "ext4"
size: 183169 MB
availableSize: 27305 MB
"/run/user/1000"
name: ""
fileSystemType: "tmpfs"
size: 6748 MB
availableSize: 6748 MB
"/media/superuser/Backups"
name: "Backups"
fileSystemType: "ext4"
size: 252113 MB
availableSize: 133173 MB
"/media/superuser/Data"
name: "Data"
fileSystemType: "ext4"
size: 732123 MB
availableSize: 694298 MB
"/media/superuser/BackupWD"
name: "BackupWD"
fileSystemType: "fuseblk"
size: 209713 MB
availableSize: 13144 MB
"/media/superuser/WDSpace"
name: "WDSpace"
fileSystemType: "fuseblk"
size: 790484 MB
availableSize: 582583 MB
```